# Mostrar componentes de Reactjs desde el backend con nodejs

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, passport

Tengo el backend con nodejs en el localhost:3030 y el frontend con reactjs en el localhost:3002. Realizo autenticación con passport:

```
//4.- Handle Signup POSt with Passport
router.route('/signup').post(passport.authenticate('signup', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    failureFlash : true 
  }));
```

Cuando la autenticación es exitosa, passport me redirecciona a una ruta del backend ('/home'), ¿Como le hago para poder renderizar una ruta del frontend cuando la ruta es correcta.

La petición que hago desde le frontend es la siguiente:

```
onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Preapring dates because they will be processed
        const user_to_check = {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }
        const answer = await axios.post('http://localhost:3003/signin',user_to_check,{withCredentials: true});
        console.log('answer'+answer); 
        //window.alert("Wating answer");
        //Refrescando la página
    }
```

No se si se relacione con lo que quiero realizar pero cuando muestro answer en consola la respuesta es: answer[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es tan complicado, simplemente cuando intentamos mostrar algo que proviene de una api como en tu caso:

```
console.log('answer'+answer);
```

no se muestro por consola exactamente lo que queremos, deberías probar solamente con:

```
console.log(answer);
```

Es que al intentar mostrar un resultado de una api al mismo tiempo que un string en un console.log podríamos decir que no se muestra el valor correctamente.

Comment: Te amo amigo, voy empezando esto de manejar el backend y fronend por separado y era algo muy sencillo. Gracias